# sort -n places 10 before 9

Tags: bash, sorting

I am trying to sort the below numbers but always its getting sorted 10 before 9.

```
$ cat disks
1I:1:1
1I:1:3
1I:1:2
1I:1:4
2I:1:5
2I:1:6
2I:1:7
2I:1:8
3I:1:9
3I:1:10
3I:1:12
3I:1:11
```

After sorting using sort -n its coming as below.

```
$ sort -n -o sorted /tmp/disks
$ cat sorted
1I:1:1
1I:1:2
1I:1:3
1I:1:4
2I:1:5
2I:1:5
2I:1:7
2I:1:8
3I:1:10
3I:1:11
3I:1:12
3I:1:9    ---> wrong sort
```

Please let me know which sort option can do this properly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by third column leaving first and second column intact in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006431/sort-by-third-column-leaving-first-and-second-column-intact-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
sort -n -t: -k3 file.txt -o out.txt
```

Comment: This worked nicely for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use version sort if your `sort` supports this option:

```
sort -V -o sorted /tmp/disks
```

Comment: That's the simple approach, KISS always works.

Answer (score 2):

The additional --stable option preserves ordering should you happen to have duplicates in column 3.

```sh
$ sort -t: -k3n --stable -o sorted /tmp/disks
$ cat sorted
1I:1:1
1I:1:2
1I:1:3
1I:1:4
2I:1:5
2I:1:6
2I:1:7
2I:1:8
3I:1:9
3I:1:10
3I:1:11
3I:1:12
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution taken care the duplicate entry also