# How to sort the multiple column of text file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to sort the multiple columns of text file out.txt  using shell script. Here is my try:

```
sort -n -k 3,4  out.txt > sorted-out1.txt
```

Comment: what are you expecting and what was the result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting multiple keys with Unix sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357560/sorting-multiple-keys-with-unix-sort)

Comment: If you look at the duplicate question/answer, I guess you want something like `sort -k3,3n -k4,4n`

Answer (score 0):

sort  -k3 -k4 sorted-out.txt> sorted-out1.txt  ,It is worked for me