# linux shell, sort column 1 in ascending order column 3 in descending order

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

my file contains 3 columns numbers, like 5 lines data below,

```
1 811036 395
2 811036 195
1 811036 295
2 811036 95
1 811036 95
```

I want to sort 1 column in ascending order and column 3 in descending order,

```
1 811036 395
1 811036 295
1 811036 95
2 811036 195
2 811036 95
```

I tried "**sort -n -k 1 -n -k 3**" but failed.
how to write a single Linux shell command to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command **`sort -k1,1n -k3,3nr`** should work.
It sorts only regarding column one (That's the difference between **-k1** and **-k1,1**) so it can reach the second argument.

Note that **`sort -k1,1n -k3nr`** probably works too.

*For more about multiple key sorting : [Sorting multiple keys with Unix sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357560/sorting-multiple-keys-with-unix-sort) or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/trying-to-sort-on-two-fields-second-then-first*

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
 sort -k1n -k3rn
```

**Explanation:**

`-k#` option: to specify the column used as a key for sorting.

`-n`: compares according to string numerical value.

`-r` : reverse the sorting order for specified key.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I do not think that it was required, though, as OP knew those flags (you can see them in the question). The point was is the arrangement of them.