# Sort a find command to respect a custom order in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I have a script that outputs file paths (via `find`), which I want to **sort based on *very specific custom logic***:

- 1st sort key:
  I want the  2nd and, if present, the 3rd `-`-separated field to be sorted using *custom* ordering based on a *list of keys* I supply - but *excluding* a numerical suffix.
  With the sample input below, the list of keys is:
  `rp,alpha,beta-ri,beta-rs,RC`
- 2nd sort key: *numeric* sorting by the *trailing number* on each line.

Given the following sample input (note that the `/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0` prefix of each line is incidental):

```
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp2
```

I expect:

```
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a variant of [my answer to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41809771/45375):

```
./your-script | awk -v keysInOrder='rp,alpha,beta-ri,beta-rs,RC' '
    BEGIN {
      FS=OFS="-"
      keyCount = split(keysInOrder, a, ",")
      for (i = 1; i <= keyCount; ++i) keysToOrdinal[a[i]] = i
    }
    { 
      sortKey = $2
      if (NF == 3) sortKey = sortKey FS $3
      sub(/[0-9]+$/, "", sortKey)
      auxFieldPrefix = "|" FS
      if (NF == 2) auxFieldPrefix = auxFieldPrefix FS
      sub(/[0-9]/, auxFieldPrefix "&", $NF)
      sortOrdinal = sortKey in keysToOrdinal ? keysToOrdinal[sortKey] : keyCount + 1
      print sortOrdinal, $0
    }
'  | sort -t- -k1,1n -k3,3 -k5,5n | sed 's/^[^-]*-//; s/|-\{1,2\}//'
```

`./your-script` represents whatever command produces the output you want to sort.

Note that an aux. character, `|`, is used to facilitate sorting, and the assumption is that this character doesn't appear in the input - which should be reasonable safe, given that filesystem paths usually don't contain pipe characters.

Any field 2 values (sans numeric suffix) that *aren't* in the list of sort keys, sort *after* the field 2/3 values that are, using alphabetic sorting among them.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not match what the OP is looking for, it would be useful to point out that `sort` command has an option `-V` for version sorting. And it does the job by following correct order of characters in ASCII table (i.e. UPPERCASE letters first, lowercase letters next)

For example:

```
cat test.sort.txt 
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp2
```

And sorting:

```
 % sort -V test.sort.txt              
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp10
```

So, it is useful to be aware of this when giving version names.

With that said, if you insisted, this is one liner that use `sed` to enforce sorting:

```
cat test.sort.txt|sed -e 's/-rp/-x1xrp/;s/-alpha/-x2xalpha/;s/-beta-ri/-x3xbeta-ri/;s/-beta-rs/-x4xbeta-rs/;s/-RC/-x5xRC/'|sort -V|sed -e 's/x.x//'
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-rp10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC10
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out a solution totally different of what @mklement0 suggests me.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a version :"
read VERSION

while read line; 
do

  find $line -type d | grep $VERSION | sort -n >> outfile.txt

  grep '.*-alpha[0-9]' outfile.txt | sort -n >> outfile2.txt 
  grep '.*-beta-ri[0-9]' outfile.txt | sort -n >> outfile2.txt 
  grep '.*-beta-rs[0-9]' outfile.txt | sort -n >> outfile2.txt 
  grep '.*-RC[0-9]' outfile.txt | sort -n >> outfile2.txt   
  rm outfile.txt 

done <whatever.txt
```

**Content of outfile2.txt :**

```
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha10
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha8
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-alpha9
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-ri2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs1
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs2
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-beta-rs3
/foo/bar/test/example/8.2.4.0-RC1
```

The only thing wrong with this is that `alpha10` came before `alpha8`

Any clue ?

Comment: You won't get correct numerical sorting if your sort keys start with non-numbers (try `sort -n <<<$'abc10\nabc2'`). Aside from that, your solution is quite inefficient.

Comment: Your sort doesnt work. Can you explain what does `<<<$abc10\nabc2` mean ?

Comment: Which sort doesn't work? `<<<` is a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) that sends its argument via _stdin_ (a single-line variation of a here-_doc_); `$'...'` is an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), in which control-character escapes such as `\n` are expanded. Not all shells support these constructs, however; here's the POSIX-compliant equivalent: `printf 'abc10\nabc2\n' | sort -n` - as you'll see, `10` sorts before `2`, i.e., the sorting is not numerical.

Comment: Re `sort -n <<<$'abc10\nabc2'`: I think I now understand where your confusion was: My intent was to use a simple example to demonstrate why your approach does _not_ work, not an attempt to show you a fix. Making your approach work - which I recommend against, due to its inefficiency - would be nontrivial, because of the varying number of fields in your input, which prevents you from using a simple  field-_index_-based `sort` command. My answer already handles all these intricacies.