# Sort numerically by all fields in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a file with multiple numbers separated by commas on each line:

```
1,13,2,5
1,3
2,3,24
1,13,2,6
```

This is just a small example file. In the real file, each line could have hundreds of numbers.

How can these be sorted numerically by field? The result should be:

```
1,3
1,13,2,5
1,13,2,6
2,3,24
```

I tried `sort -n -t,`, but that compares lines as numbers, producing the wrong result.

Comment: Tell sort which keys to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357560/sorting-multiple-keys-with-unix-sort

Comment: How can I do that when the list on each line can contain hundreds of numbers, and I want to sort by all of them?

Comment: Also, the number of keys varies by line

Comment: First, you asked to sort by field, so choose your field and sort by that. Second, if the number of keys varies by line, how can you sort over a key that is inexistent on some lines:

Comment: 1)I changed the title to reflect your comment, 2)sort with the assumption is that null<any, like in a dictionary where `car` comes before `cart`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually quite a subtle problem, to do with the way `sort` handles numeric fields. The upshot is that you need to explicitly tell `sort` to sort numerically on each key field:

```
sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n
```

If you don't do that, the `info` section for GNU `sort` says, slightly paraphrased,

> `sort` would have used all characters beginning in the [first] field and
>   extending to the end of the line as the primary numeric key.  For
>   the large majority of applications, treating keys spanning more
>   than one field as numeric will not do what you expect.

which neatly summarises what you saw!

Obviously specifying keys explicitly is going to make `sort` inconvenient to use on files with arbitrarily long lists of numbers on each line. As a hack, you could try GNU `sort` with its version sort option, `-V`.

```
sort -V
```

which appears to do the right thing on your particular data. I've tested `sort -V` on lines with 600 numbers, and it works fine.

Comment: So your answer only works if all fields are present, and I mention them explicitly in the sort parameters. I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear, but that's not what I'm asking

Comment: @MrMartin It turns out `sort -V` works on your data. I'd never heard of the `-V` option before now. Thanks for the great question!

Comment: Amazing answer!